# Emacs inside Emacs: how to exit inner emacs without exiting main one

Tags: git, emacs

I'm moving to emacs.
I am running a zsh terminal in my emacs, and I set up my git editor as `emacs -nw`.

so now I'm doing a rebase on my emacs terminal, and the emacs editor is shown with the content of my commits. 
My question is how to actually save + exit the emacs within this terminal?
as doing C-x C-c exits the main emacs (Closing/killing) everything

I'm slowly moving to emacs and I don't intend to use magit, so don't consider it as a solution.

Comment: Nothing wrong with wanting to take it slow, but magit is neither such a time investment, nor is the value of learning it trivial. If you end up doing more advanced git things(rebaseing and such), which turn out to be "advanced" only because the default UI is so horrible, you'll want a better interface. So take your time, but my advice is to eventually get to it, it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure `core.editor` in git to something like `/usr/bin/emacsclient --alternate-editor /usr/bin/emacs` (add -nw if you need it).

Then you just need to add to your emacs init file this:

```
(unless (server-running-p) (server-start)))
```

to start emacs server when you start emacs (unless you have another emacs running, something experienced emacs user don't usually do)

When you do a git commit or interactive rebase, a new buffer will open in your emacs.  You made the changes and do `C-x #` (or your keybinding to server-edit) and git will continue from there.

If emacs is not already running, the `--alternate-editor` will take over.